Integral of the product of a Gaussian and a exponential of a hyperbolic function
In a derivation I am working on, I have encountered an integral of the form
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a x^2-b\ \textrm{cosh}(x)}\ dx
\end{equation}
with $a$ and $b$ real and positive. I am not sure if there is a closed form. Any ideas on how to attack it?
Edit: Building upon the approach proposed by @Sam, we can express
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a x^2-b\ \textrm{cosh}(x)}\ dx = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n}}{a}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2n)!}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
a_{2n}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
e^{-b}\qquad &n=1\\
-b\ e^{-b}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T_{n,k+1}(-1)^kb^k \qquad & n\geq 1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
and $T_{n,k}$ the triangle defined by the OEIS sequence A156289. Making use of the closed expression for $T_{n,k}$, we have
\begin{equation}
a_{2n}=-b\ e^{-b}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{2k+2}{k-j}\frac{(-1)^j(j+1)^{2n}}{(k+1)!}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^k \qquad \qquad n\geq 1
\end{equation}
Putting all the pieces together,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a x^2-b\ \textrm{cosh}(x)}\ dx = \frac{e^{-b}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left[1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{2k+2}{k-j}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}(j+1)^{2n}}{(k+1)!\ n!\ 2^{k+2n}}\frac{b^{k+1}}{a^{n}}\right]
\end{equation}
Making use of the modified Bessel function of the first kind, it should be possible to perform the sums in $k$ and $j$ and get the more compact and elegantly derived expression by @Leucippus,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a x^2-b\ \textrm{cosh}(x)}\ dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \, \left( I_{0}(b) + 2 \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, I_{n}(b) \, e^{n^2/(4 a)} \right)
\end{equation}
This expansion is valid except far from $a^{-1}=0$. In particular, it breaks for $a=0$, where the integral is still convergent
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-b\ \textrm{cosh}(x)}\ dx = K_0(b)
\end{equation}
Any thoughts on how to express the integral as an expansion around $a=0$?

Where is the integral from?

@ТymaGaidash It comes from the computation of the quantum wavefunction of a particle in some curved space I am working on. I have not encountered this type of integral before

Are there any particular values of $a$ and $b$ for which you are evaluating this integral ? @STU

@Sam I am mostly interested in a closed form for further symbolic manipulation rather than in numerically evaluating the integral. In my application, the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are complex functions of various physical constants (Planck constant, curvature, etc.).

@STU are you a physicist??

By using
$$ e^{-z \, \cosh(\theta)} = I_{0}(z) + 2 \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, I_{n}(z) \, \cosh(n \theta) $$
and
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- a \, x^2} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \\
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- a \, x^2} \, \cosh(n x) \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \, e^{n^2/(4 a)}
\end{align*}
then
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- a \, x^2 - b \, \cosh(x)} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \, \left( I_{0}(b) + 2 \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \, I_{n}(b) \, e^{n^2/(4 a)} \right). $$
Note that as $n$ increases so does the exponential in the summation. If $I_{n}(b)$ does not compensate for the growth as $n$ gets large then the series will certainly diverge, or at least have issues. This solution sets forth a plan of attack and has avoided the consideration(s) for the series to be absolutely convergent. This is a good exercise for the reader.

This is the kind of thing I was looking for. It is in spirit the same strategy as the one proposed by @Sam, but elegantly implemented in terms of the modified Bessel function $I_n(b)$. As you note, a limitation of this general strategy is that results in an expansion around $a^{-1}=0$, while the integral converges also at $a=0$.

It should be:$$e^{-z \cosh (\theta )}=I_0(z)+2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n I_n(z) \cosh (n \theta )$$

From 10.35.2 at https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.35.

Define $h(x) = e^{-b\cosh{x}}$ and denote $I$ as the integral in question. Since $h$ is an even function, $h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ where $a_{2n}$ is the $(2n)$th derivative of $h$ at zero, that is, $a_{2n} = h^{(2n)}(0)$. Substituting this in the integral, we obtain $$\begin{align*} 
I = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{2n}}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx \overset{ax^2=t}{=} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n}}{a^n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2n)!}. \end{align*}$$
The coefficients $a_{2n}$ can be solved recursively as follows: Differentiating, $h'(x) = -b\sinh{(x)}h(x)$ and $h''(x) = -b[ \cosh{(x)}h(x)+\sinh{(x)}h'(x)]$. Differentiating both sides $2n$ times and using Lebiniz rule of differentiation, $$ h^{2(n+1)}(x) = -b\left[\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}\cosh^{(2n-r)}(x)h^{(r)}(x)+\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}\sinh^{(2n-r)}{(x)}h^{(r+1)}(x) \right].$$
Since we only need to evaluate it at $x=0$, only even and odd $r$ terms survive in the first and second sum respectively as $\sinh(0)=0$. Thus, $$ a_{2n+2} = -b\left[\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2r}a_{2r}+\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{2r-1}a_{2r} \right].$$
Using the Binomial identity $\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r} = \binom{n}{r}$, $$a_{2n+2} = -b\left[a_0 + \sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2r}a_{2r}\right],\quad n\ge 0.$$
Using this formula, $$\begin{gather*} a_0 = e^{-b}, \quad a_2 = -be^{-b}\\
a_4 = -b\left[a_0+\binom{3}{2}a_2 \right] = b(3b-1)e^{-b}\\
a_6 = -b\left[a_0+\binom{5}{2}a_2+\binom{5}{4}a_4\right] = -b(15b^2-15b+1)e^{-b}\\
a_8 = -b\left[a_0+\binom{7}{2}a_2+\binom{7}{4}a_4+\binom{7}{6}a_6\right]=b(105b^3-210b^2+63b-1)e^{-b}.\end{gather*}$$
Edit: If $a$ is small, more terms might be required in the sum for a good approximation. For instance if $a=0.01$ , then I would take atleast $16$ terms in the sum as $(0.01)^{16}*32! \approx 2631.31$.

Thanks, that is a great take! A non-recursive form for the coefficients $a_{2n}$ can be constructed by using the close form of the OEIS sequence A156289. I will edit my post to include the non-recursive expression based on your approach.

Your welcome. That's interesting, didn't know these coefficients were part of a sequence.
